# Proof that momentum operator acting on a wavefunction gives the expectation value

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, momentum, wavefunction

I'm following a book where the author tries to prove that $$\langle p \rangle = \langle \psi \vert \hat{p} \vert \psi \rangle,\tag{0}$$ so he just computes the integral

$$
\langle \psi \vert \hat{p} \vert \psi \rangle
~=~ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \psi^*(x) \left( -i\hbar \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \right) \psi(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
\tag{1}
$$

and starts by saying that

$$
-i\hbar\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\psi(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}
~=~ -i\hbar\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \tilde{\psi}(p) e^{ipx/\hbar} \, \mathrm{d}p
~=~ \int_{\mathbb{R}} p \, \tilde{\psi}(p) \, e^{ipx/\hbar} \, \mathrm{d}p
\tag{2}
$$

which is okay because we can expand the wavefunction on the position space as a sum of wavefunctions on the momentum space using the Fourier transform on $\psi(x) .$

Using this result, we have that

$$
\langle \psi \vert \hat{p} \vert \psi \rangle
~=~ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} \tilde{\psi}^*(p') \, e^{ip'x/\hbar} \mathrm{d}p' \right) \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} p \, \tilde{\psi}(p) \, e^{ipx/\hbar} \mathrm{d}p \right) \mathrm{d}x
\tag{3}
$$

However, I don't get why the next two steps are mathematically correct and how he moves the integration signs:

$$
\begin{align}
\langle \psi \vert \hat{p} \vert \psi \rangle
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} p\, \tilde{\psi}^*(p')\, \tilde{\psi}(p) \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i(p-p')x/\hbar} dx\right) \, \mathrm{d}p' \, \mathrm{d}p
\tag{4}
\\[5px]
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \delta(p-p') \,p\, \tilde{\psi}^*(p')\, \tilde{\psi}(p) \, \mathrm{d}p \, \mathrm{d}p'
\tag{5}
\\[5px]
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} p \vert \tilde{\psi}(p) \vert^2 \, \mathrm{d}p
\tag{6}
\\[5px]
&= \langle p \rangle
\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$

Eq. (7) obviously follows from Eq. (6), because the expectation value of a random variable is equal to the integral of that variable times the probability density distribution, which is exactly what $\vert\tilde{\psi}(p)\vert^2$ is.  But how does he get to Eq. (6)?

**Question:**  How do we get Equations (5) and (6) starting from Equation (4)?

Comment: I do not understand this question - $\langle p\rangle$ and $\langle \psi \vert \hat{p} \vert \psi\rangle$  are for me just two notations for the same thing. What exactly is the thing you want to prove here?

Comment: Which textbook?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I suspect that Jamie_mc2 is using $\langle p\rangle$ to mean the statistical expectation value, i.e. $\langle X\rangle = E[X] = \int X P(X) \mathrm{d}X$, which is not a priori the same thing as a matrix element of an operator like $\langle\psi|\hat{p}|\psi\rangle$.

Comment: Yes @DavidZ that was exactly what I meant. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From eq. (4) to eq. (5): The Fourier transform of $1$ is the $\delta$ function, i.e. $\int \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}px}\mathrm{d}p = \delta(x)$, cf. e.g. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-Distribution#Fourier-Transformation).

From eq. (5) to eq. (6): This is just the characteristic property of the $\delta$-function, i.e. $\int f(x) \delta(x - y) \mathrm{x} = f(y)$.

Comment: There are $2\pi$'s  missing everywhere: $\int e^{ipx}dp = 2\pi \delta(x)$