# How to find the expectation value of momentum operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, momentum, fourier-transform

I have struggled with the following steps in finding the expectation value of the momentum operator $\hat{p}$.
$$\left \langle \hat{p} \right \rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi^{*}(x)\hat{p}\psi{x}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi^{*}(x)\left(-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\psi(x) dx\tag{1}$$
$$\left \langle \hat{p} \right \rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi^{*}(x)\left(-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)dx\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{ipx}{\hbar}}\phi(p)dp\tag{2}$$
Where $\psi(x)$ is written as the Fourier transform of the momentum space. Now,
$$\left \langle \hat{p} \right \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(p)p\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi^{*}(x)e^{\frac{ipx}{\hbar}}dp\tag{3}$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(p)p\phi^*(p)\tag{4}$$

In the step 3, as we can see clearly, the momentum operator $-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ became just $p$. How is it possible?

Comment: Hint: What is the position operator **in the position basis**?

Comment: Yes, got it. It's just the position. In the momentum space, it must be just the momentum. Right?

Comment: You must tell us what is "step 3", please add ``\tag{3}`` at the end in the TeX input for the equation you maen.

Comment: You have badly misplaced dx and dp in your formulas, which might be the source of your confusion.

Comment: Pretty pretty close dupe: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/497521/proof-that-momentum-operator-acting-on-a-wavefunction-gives-the-expectation-valu?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I am going to rewrite your formulas because the placement of some of your quantities is personally confusing.

$$\left \langle \hat{p} \right \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \ \psi^{*}(x)\left(-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\psi(x), \tag{1}$$
which is just expressing $\langle \hat{p} \rangle_{\lvert \psi \rangle}$ in the position basis. Strictly speaking, the first equality you included in expression $(1)$ is incorrect. Now, we recall the definitions
$$\psi(x) = \langle x \lvert \psi \rangle $$
and
$$\psi(p) = \langle p \lvert \psi \rangle$$
to obtain
$$\psi(x) = \int dp \ \langle x \lvert p \rangle \langle p \lvert \psi \rangle = \int dp \ e^{ipx}\psi(p)$$
where we have used the completeness relation. Substituting this expression of $\psi(x)$ into $(1)$, we obtain
$$\left \langle \hat{p} \right \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \left[ \left( \int_{-\infty}^\infty dp \ e^{-ipx/\hbar} \psi^*(p)\right)\left(-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right) \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp' \  e^{ip'x/\hbar}\psi(p')\right) \right]. \tag{2}$$
Now, pulling the differential into the rightmost integral, we obtain
$$\left \langle \hat{p} \right \rangle= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \left[ \left( \int_{-\infty}^\infty dp \ e^{ipx/\hbar} \psi^*(p)\right) \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp' p '\  e^{-ip'x/\hbar}\psi(p')\right) \right], \tag{3}$$
which further simplifies to
$$\langle \hat{p} \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \left[ \int_{-\infty}^\infty dp \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp' \ e^{ipx/\hbar} \psi^*(p) p' \  e^{-ip'x/\hbar}\psi(p') \right]$$
$$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \left[ \int_{-\infty}^\infty dp \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp' \ \psi^*(p) p' \psi(p') e^{ipx/\hbar -ip'x/\hbar} \right]$$
$$= \int_{-\infty}^\infty dp \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp' \ \psi^*(p) p' \psi(p') \delta(p - p')$$
$$= \int_{-\infty}^\infty dp \ \psi^*(p) p \psi(p).$$
This is just the expectation value of the momentum operator in the momentum basis. So the momentum operator expressed in the position basis is now expressed in the momentum basis. In the momentum basis, the momentum operator is expressed as the momentum $p$.

---

Note: Arguably, the majority of this computation is much easier in bra-ket notation. By definition
$$\langle \hat{p} \rangle_{\lvert \psi \rangle} = \langle \psi \lvert \hat{p} \lvert \psi \rangle$$
$$= \int \ dx \langle \psi \lvert x \rangle \langle x \lvert \hat{p} \lvert x \rangle \langle x \lvert \psi \rangle$$
$$= \int \ dp \langle \psi \lvert p \rangle \langle p \lvert \hat{p} \lvert p \rangle \langle p \lvert \psi \rangle$$
by inserting two completeness relations. You know that $\langle x \lvert \hat{p} \lvert x \rangle = -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, $\langle x \lvert \psi \rangle = \psi(x)$, $\langle p \lvert \hat{p} \lvert p \rangle = p$, and $\langle p \lvert \psi \rangle = \psi(p)$.